# What does "wear a different aspect" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

Look at the following excerpt of THE DESCENT OF MAN by Charles Darwin:

> During many years I collected notes on the origin or
>   descent of man, without any intention of publishing on
>   the subject . . . as I thought that I should thus only add to
>   the prejudices against my views. . . . **Now the case wears a wholly different aspect.** . . . it is manifest that at
>   least a large number of naturalists must admit that
>   species are the modified descendants of other species; and this especially holds good with the younger and
>   rising naturalists.

I know the meaning of each word, but what is the meaning of *the case wears a different aspect*?

Comment: Whats this from, I'm English and it sounds strange to me? Do you have any more context?

Comment: @User112638726  I added more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the preceding sentence reveals some new information that should cause you to change your opinion of the topic.  Metaphorically, the topic is now dressed in (*wears*) different clothing, which alters its appearance (*aspect*).

**Later:** I wrote this answer before the asker added the paragraph in which the sentence appears.  I would change it only to note that the clothing was changed not by new information revealed in the preceding sentence, but by events since the first publication of *The Origin*.